# ssh ethernet tunneling as normal user

Tags: opensuse, ssh-tunneling, privileges

I would like to connect 2 tap-devices. The tap-device on the remote server is owned by "user". This is my test-command:

```
# ssh -oTunnel=ethernet -w0:0 user@server
```

But it does not work, I get this error:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

On the server, the tap-devices are created by some mechanism of opensuse. The configuration files are /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-tap[0-2]:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
STARTMODE='auto'
TUNNEL='tap'
TUNNEL_SET_GROUP=''
TUNNEL_SET_OWNER='user'
```

and /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-br0:

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BRIDGE='yes'
BRIDGE_FORWARDDELAY='0'
BRIDGE_PORTS='tap0 tap1 tap2'
BRIDGE_STP='off'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='192.168.1.103/24'
MTU=''
NAME=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
```

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi. What distro and location?

Comment: I am little confused. I was about to answer "not" because I remember it once said in the man page that you require root privileges on your client to create a tun or tap device, but I cant find that remark i neither `ssh` nor `ssh_config` man pages. So I guess I don't have an answer for you. :-(

Comment: The tap already exists and is owned by the user. ssh just has to attach to it. As root, there is no problem, but I prefer to use a normal user.

Comment: As you say, the easiest way is doing as root on both sides. I also do not feel confy doing it.

Comment: @A.B: of course, PermitTunnel = yes. There does not seem to be SELinux/Apparmor on the server. There is no such problem with qemu, that can attach to tap devices without problems here... So I guess, that the problem is specific to sshd.

Comment: made the setup myself using ip tuntap. works here through ssh: you'll have to describe all the steps you went through (especially the use of ip tuntap or any other method to configure the tap device)

Comment: @A.B: Thanks, you're right. It works with "ip tuntap". But when openSUSE creates the interfaces, it does not work. So I guess, I have to ask openSUSE for help or create the interfaces by hand... (I don't know, how openSUSE creates the tap devices.)

Comment: @A.B: The tap *is* correctly owned by the user. Even when configured by openSUSE, as confirmed by /sys/class/net/tap0/owner. The question is rather: where is the difference between the setup by openSUSE and "ip tuntap"...

Comment: You should add this in the question, and add an opensuse tag (since it might be specific).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this works (thanks to A.B):

1.) remove the relevant files in /etc/sysconfig/network

2.) systemctl restart network

3.) create the same setup with the "ip" tool:

```
ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user user
ip tuntap add tap1 mode tap user user
ip tuntap add tap2 mode tap user user
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set tap0 master br0
ip link set tap1 master br0
ip link set tap2 master br0
ip addr add dev br0 192.168.1.103/24
ip link set br0 up
ip link set tap0 up
ip link set tap1 up
ip link set tap2 up
```

Of course, this is only a workaround. A better answer would be, that still uses the openSUSE provided mechanism.